# How to change the font of the Android console in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, console, font-size

The question is given, I want a smaller font to display these lines in the Android Console window (NOT the Logcat window). I've changed the *other* console's font (cvs, svn, ...) in the preferences, but this window still has same font size. I want this window to be much smaller and put it on the side of my screen, not on the bottom, this way I would have vertically more space in Eclipse.

`[2010-08-02 16:26:58 - project1] ------------------------------

[2010-08-02 16:26:58 - project1] Android Launch!

[2010-08-02 16:26:58 - project1] adb is running normally.

[2010-08-02 16:26:58 - project1] Performing ...Activity activity launch

[2010-08-02 16:26:59 - project1] Uploading project1.apk onto device 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

[2010-08-02 16:27:03 - project1] Installing project1.apk...

[2010-08-02 16:27:20 - project1] Success!`


Could any of you change this window's font size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Android console doesn't seem to apply font changes until Eclipse is relaunched. I found that changes to *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font* applied to the Android console after relaunch.

Comment: That restart fooled me :). Thanks!
BTW: the main editor's font also changes, but this is why it's: "Basic Text Font".

Answer (score 2):

From Eclipse documentation you find this:

To set the fonts used in the Console view:

Open the   General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts preference page.
Select Console font from the Debug category and use the Change... button to change the font.  (The Detail Pane Text Font can be used to change the font of the debugger's default Detail Pane).

Ref: [Help Eclipse-SDK](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-consoleAppearance.htm)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this but this sets the font for other console windows. As stated above. This does not help me, sorry.

Comment: Helped me, because I was going for the regular java console, thanks!